# How to write the esql code for a json response from the json request as input?

Tags: arrays, json, ibm-integration-bus

request->

```
{
    "data": 
      {
      "type": "employee",
      "attributes": 
           [
            {
             "name": "Sam",
             "empId": 1,
             "grade": "A"
            },
            {
             "name": "Barsa",
             "empId": 2,
             "grade": "A"
            },
             "name": "Ram",
             "empId": 3,
             "grade": "B"
            }
           ]
       }
}
```

response->##

---

```
 ##
{
    "data": 
      {
      "type": "grade",
      "employees": 
           [
            {
             "name": "Sam",
             "empId": 1,
             "grade": "A"
            },
            {
             "name": "Barsa",
             "empId": 2,
             "grade": "A"
            },
             "name": "Ram",
             "empId": 3,
             "grade": "B"
            }
           ]
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chapters [Modifying a JSON message](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=domain-modifying-json-message) and [SET statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=statements-set-statement) explain how to do the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    SET OutputRoot = InputRoot;
    SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.data.type = 'grade';
    SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.data.attributes NAME = 'employees';
    RETURN TRUE;
END;
```

NOTE: Your request message is invalid json: The `{` before `"name": "Ram",` is missing.